# htaccess - skip URL past root level

Tags: .htaccess, directory, root, forward

Been trying all sorts of ways can't seem to figure out how to get the following result. I want my url to grab everything up to a specific point, link through that file and skip rest of url. The rest of the url is however necessary for my include files so I want it to remain in the URL.

This is the result I'm after:

www.homepage.com/index/somepage, This would open "index.php" and do nothing else.

www.homepage.com/stuff/someotherpage, This would open "stuff.php" and do nothing else.

So it's quite simple but I just can't figure out how to make this happen when using multiple pages. I can make it simply redirect to index.php every time, but that's not the result I want.

Progress so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Force everything through the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start this way, capturing the first part of the URL and redirect to this page .php

You can change the ([a-z]+) if you have more complex page name.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Force everything through the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*) $1.php?param_url=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can I hook it up so that it always uses the first section of a url and the second part is just ignored?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what it does :)